# GoogleApiClient is not connected despite onconnect() being called?

Tags: android

I want to add a geofence on the current location of the user when the user clicks on the ad geofence button.however,after using fused api client it states that its not connected yet.here is my code-

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.Geofence;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private GoogleMap googleMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.
    public SQLiteDatabase db;
    ArrayList<Geofence> mGeofences;
    public double latitude = 77.80;
    public double longitude = 55.76;
    Double valueindex = 0.0;
    private int request = 0;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    /**
     * Geofence Coordinates
     */
    ArrayList<LatLng> mGeofenceCoordinates;
    /**
     * Geofence Store
     */
    private GeofenceStore mGeofenceStore;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mGeofences = new ArrayList<Geofence>();
        mGeofenceCoordinates = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        db = openOrCreateDatabase("CoordsDB", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
//        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Coordinates(number DOUBLE,latitude DOUBLE,longitude DOUBLE);");
//        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Coordinates VALUES('Fixed', 28.61,77.20)");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment =
                (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.googleMap);
        /**
         * SupportMapFragment belongs to the v4 support library, contrary to the default MagFragment that is a native component in Android.
         SupportMapFragment will support more Android versions, but it is also an additional library you have to add in your project,
         so I think it really depends on the Android versions you are targeting:
         •  On recent versions, the default components should be enough
         •  On older versions you will need to install the v4 support library and maybe others
         *
         */
        googleMap = supportMapFragment.getMap();
        Log.i("My activity", "maps=" + googleMap);
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        /**
         * setMyLocationEnabled(true/false) shows the true location when the GPS is switched on from the device. It is an inbuilt feature of the googlemaps .
         */

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Service.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        // getting GPS status
        boolean isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        Log.i("My activity", "gps is" + isGPSEnabled);

        // getting network status
        boolean isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        Log.i("My activity", "network is" + isNetworkEnabled);

        Criteria crta = new Criteria();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
            crta.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        } else {
            crta.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_MEDIUM);
        }
        /**
         * we have used .setAccuracy as fine for higher SDks than gingerbread .Gingerbread is used as a reference because in apks lower
         * than gingerbread there is very poor geofencing, with gingerbread google made it a lot easier for locationservices to be used for devleopers.
         * it had improved set of tools for Location Services, which included geofencing and substantially improved location discovery.
         */
        crta.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(crta, true);

        /**
         * It request Location updates after every 5 sec or if the user traveled 10m
         */
        Log.i("My activity", "manager is " + locationManager);
        Log.i("My activity", "provider is " + provider);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                MapsActivity.this.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 100);
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for Activity#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
        }
        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks((GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks) this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener((GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener) this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            Log.i("Api is",""+mGoogleApiClient);
        }
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        // We want a location update every 10 seconds.
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000);
        // We want the location to be as accurate as possible.
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

//        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                mGoogleApiClient);
        startLocationUpdates();
        Log.i("Location is", location + "");



        if (location != null) {

            onLocationChanged(location);
        }


        /**
         * the Permission is requested after every  sec or at a distance of 0 metres by the user.
         */


    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 100: {
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Thanks for the permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    // permission was granted, yay! do the
                    // calendar task you need to do.
                } else {
                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.
                    Toast.makeText(this, "You did not allow to access your current location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
            // other 'switch' lines to check for other
            // permissions this app might request
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        CameraPosition INIT =
                new CameraPosition.Builder()
                        .target(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()))
                        .zoom(17.5F)
                        .bearing(300F) // orientation
                        .tilt(50F) // viewing angle
                        .build();
        // use GooggleMap mMap to move camera into position
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(INIT));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {

        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {

        super.onStop();
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();

    }


    public void Add(View view) {
        if (request <= 3) {
            mGeofenceCoordinates.add(new LatLng(latitude, longitude));
            Log.i("The id is", "" + valueindex);
            mGeofences.add(new Geofence.Builder()
                    // The coordinates of the center of the geofence and the radius in meters.
                    .setRequestId("" + valueindex)
                    .setCircularRegion(latitude, longitude, 30)
                    .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
                            // Required when we use the transition type of GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL
                    .setLoiteringDelay(50000)
                    .setTransitionTypes(
                            Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER
                                    | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL
                                    | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT).build());
            mGeofenceStore = new GeofenceStore(this, mGeofences);
            valueindex++;
            request++;

//            Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Coordinates WHERE Id='"+valueindex+"'", null);


            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().snippet("Radius:30m").draggable(false).title(valueindex + "").position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)));
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Maximum limit exceeded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Location mlastlocation;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                MapsActivity.this.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 100);
                //    public void requestPermissions(@NonNull String[] permissions, int requestCode)
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for Activity#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
        }
            mlastlocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                    mGoogleApiClient);
           startLocationUpdates();
            if (mlastlocation != null) {
                Log.i("the last location:", "" + mlastlocation);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Get last location first asshole!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


        }


    protected void startLocationUpdates() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                MapsActivity.this.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 100);
                //    public void requestPermissions(@NonNull String[] permissions, int requestCode)
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for Activity#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
            LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();

            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                    mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.i("connection","suspended");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.i("Connection","Failed");
    }
}
```

Here is my error-

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{saksham.geofencing/saksham.geofencing.MapsActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet.
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2426)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet.
            at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzh.zzb(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzl.zzb(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzj.zzb(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.location.internal.zzd.requestLocationUpdates(Unknown Source)
            at saksham.geofencing.MapsActivity.startLocationUpdates(MapsActivity.java:276)
            at saksham.geofencing.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:139)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6245)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

and my manifest file-

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="saksham.geofencing" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <!--
 The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
    <receiver android:name="com.aol.android.geofence.GeofenceReceiver"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="com.aol.android.geofence.ACTION_RECEIVE_GEOFENCE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</manifest>
```

Please help,i am newbie to android and i have been stuck at it for many days now even after searching countless blogs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `onCreate` method, you correctly configure the Google API Client and call `onConnect`:

```
if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks((GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks) this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener((GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener) this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    Log.i("Api is",""+mGoogleApiClient);
}
```

However, several lines below this (still within the `onCreate` lifecycle method), you have the following code:

```
Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
            mGoogleApiClient);
startLocationUpdates();
Log.i("Location is", location + "");

if (location != null) {
    onLocationChanged(location);
}
```

My guess is that the first line of this section is causing the error - you are trying to retrieve a location but the Google API Client is still not connected at this point. Since you already have analogous code inside your `onConnected` callback, you should be able to just remove the second block of code I quoted above from your `onCreate` method to fix the issue.